# Kivy on_press method fires twice

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

When running the following code:

```
class JumpingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = JumpingGame()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
        return game

class JumpingGame(ButtonBehavior, Widget):
    def update(self,dt):
        pass

    def on_press(self):
        print("1")
        print("2")

if __name__=="__main__":
    JumpingApp().run()
```

with the .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9


<JumpingGame>:
    on_press: self.on_press()
```

the following happens;
when I click the Display the on_press() method of JumpingGame fires twice,
so the output isnt't

```
1
2
```

but

```
1
2
1
2
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the Problem :
I had to delete the line:

```
on_press: self.on_press()
```

in the .kv file because on_press is the standart name so it executed the method twice